# Parsing RSS XML data on server side using Parse.com Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, xml, rss, parse-platform

I want to write a function in Parse clod code that periodically reads an XML file and checks whether there is a new entry and does something if there is.

The main question:
1. Where do I write the logic/function to do this. If it is a function, where is it called?

On a side note:
2. Is it possible to store variables in Parse cloud code? To be more precise, can I read an xml file the first time and store the title, then on the second read check the title against the title from the previous read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I asked this yesterday and never got an answer. Solved it myself eventually so i'll jus tout an answer here for completeness sake. If anyone else has a better idea, add that too.

**For the first question:**

-Write a cloud function in {Cloud code folder name}/cloud/main.js to parse xml.

-Write a background job in the same js file to call the function above.

-In your parse.com dashboard for the app, set the schedule details of the job under the Cloud code section.

**For the second question:**

Global variables can't be used in Parse.com cloud code. Instead store these variables in a Parse class (table) and access it from your client and/or cloud side.